# Flash: PNG in the library vs loading PNGS

Tags: flash, image, graphics, png

I have a series of PNG files I need to use in a Flash project.

Usually I bulk load my PNGs via an xml or json page.

I'm just wondering, what is the difference between loading PNG files this way and adding a PNG to the stage via the Library (say, if you imported a PNG file to the library and then added it to the stage via Actionscript OR if you just dragged it on the stage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Loading the PNG files when you access the SWF file allows the SWF to run smoother in the Flash player from the internet. The initial download of the SWF file will be quick.  This allows you to display something to the user to indicate that the swf file is working and needs to just retrieve a few more things before continuing.  Depending on the use of the SWF file, you might want the SWF file download the PNG's as it needs it.  For example, a web image gallery create in Flash should probably only download the pictures for the page that the user is on.
2. Importing into the Flash library during design phase makes the initial download of the file huge.  It could discourage the user from continuing the download. The user might think the file is bad or timed out if the download is too long.  Remember that the SWF will not display on the browser until the whole file is downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are 2 obvious difference IMHO.

1. You reduce the size of your swf when you load them externally.  You not only reduce the size of your final swf, but you reduce the size of your fla which can be nice when opening, saving, closing, opening.
2. You have easier access to modify the images because they are loaded externally.  Updating an asset doesn't require opening, modifying and recompiling the swf.  You only have to update the asset being loaded.

Depending on what the assets are being loaded via xml,json or being placed on the stage there can be additional differences.

If they are one-off assets, that are used for the UI, having them on the stage is nice to be able to maintain layout.  Positioning everything precisely is difficult to do without the actual assets on the stage.

My rule of thumb, is load everything on the stage that is a visual asset that is part of the UI itself.  If the image is only part of the asset that will be loaded several times (for instance a thumbnail gallery) then I never place all of the images in the library.  Hope this makes sense, havent' had my coffee yet.